# Apply function to dataframe row in pandas based on value in specific column

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have pandas dataframe, where first column is threshold:

```
threshold,value1,value2,value3,...,valueN
5,12,3,4,...,20
4,1,7,8,...,3
7,5,2,8,...,10
```

And for each row I want set elements in columns `value1..valueN` to zero if it less then `threshold`:

```
threshold,value1,value2,value3,...,valueN
5,12,0,0,...,20
4,0,7,8,...,0
7,0,0,8,...,10
```

How can I do this without explicit `for` loops?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) for compare with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.lt(df['threshold'], axis=0), 0)
```

Or[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and  [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('threshold')
df = df.mask(df.lt(df.index, axis=0), 0).reset_index()
```

---

For improve performance `numpy solution`:

```
arr = df.values
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(arr < arr[:, 0][:, None], 0, arr), columns=df.columns)
```

---

```
print (df)
   threshold  value1  value2  value3  valueN
0          5      12       0       0      20
1          4       0       7       8       0
2          7       0       0       8      10
```

**Timings**:

```
In [294]: %timeit set_reset_sol(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 376 ms per loop

In [295]: %timeit numpy_sol(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.9 ms per loop

In [296]: %timeit df.mask(df.lt(df['threshold'], axis=0), 0)
1 loop, best of 3: 380 ms per loop

In [297]: %timeit df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.threshold, x, 0), axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 449 ms per loop


np.random.seed(234)
N = 100000

#[100000 rows x 100 columns] 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(N, 100)))
df.columns = ['threshold'] + df.columns[1:].tolist()
print (df)

def set_reset_sol(df):
    df = df.set_index('threshold')
    return df.mask(df.lt(df.index, axis=0), 0).reset_index()

def numpy_sol(df):
    arr = df.values
    return pd.DataFrame(np.where(arr < arr[:, 0][:, None], 0, arr), columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try in this way:

```
df.iloc[:,1:] = df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: np.where(x > df.threshold, x, 0), axis=0)
```

Comment: Right, but he says explicit